# Is that proved that breaking ECDSA as hard as solving ECDLP?

Tags: cryptography, ecdsa

Is that proved that breaking ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) as hard as solving ECDLP(Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem)?

Comment: This is better suited for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, correct. Thank you. I'll remove from here.

Comment: I think it is fine here. libsecp is Bitcoin https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1